# Applescript Realistic Keystroke

Tags: applescript, keystroke

Is it possible to use Applescript to type text at a randomised speed quickly & efficiently?  I have the following script:

On run {input, parameters}:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "H"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "i"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "t"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "h"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "e"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "r"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "e"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "!"
    delay 0.1
    key code 36
    delay 0.5
    keystroke "H"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "o"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "w"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "a"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "r"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "e"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "y"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "o"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "u"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "?"
    delay 0.2
    key code 36
    delay 1.0
    keystroke "W"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "h"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "e"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "r"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "e"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "d"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "o"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "y"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "o"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "u"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "w"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "a"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "n"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "t"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "t"
    delay 0.3
    keystroke "o"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke " "
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "b"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "e"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "g"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "i"
    delay 0.2
    keystroke "n"
    delay 0.1
    keystroke "?"
end tell

return input
end run
```

I basically, want to type all of the words (for 1 line at least) in one keystroke (or similar command), and then use a random delay such as the below between each key.  Is it possible?

```
delay (random number from 0.05 to 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it - http://christianheilmann.com/2014/01/09/autmating-typing-in-screencasts-with-applescript-or-how-to-look-like-a-hollywood-hacker/

You just need to create a file (I used a .txt file rather than a .js file), specify the location & hey presto.

Heres my tweak with randomised text speed:

```
set fc to read POSIX file "/test/testdoc.txt" as «class utf8»

set the text item delimiters to (ASCII character 10)
set mylines to text items in fc
repeat with currentline in mylines
    write_string(currentline)
end repeat

on write_string(the_string)
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "textedit" to activate
        delay 10
        repeat with the_character in the_string
            keystroke the_character
            delay (random number from 0.05 to 0.25)
        end repeat
        key code 36
        key code 123 using command down
    end tell
end write_string
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind that there are no returns then use this:

```
delay 3 

set new_array to "h, i, ,  t, h, e, r, e, !,  , h, o, w,  , a, r, e,  , y, o, u, ?,  , w, h, e, r, e,  , d, o,  , y, o, u,  , w, a, n, t,  , t, o,  , b, e, g, i, n, ?"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set the list_items to every text item of the new_array
set a to list_items
set b to count of list_items
set c to 0
tell application "System Events"
repeat b times
    set c to c + 1
    delay (random number from 0.05 to 0.3)
    keystroke item c of a
end repeat
end tell
```

But if you want the returns then use this:

```
delay 3
set a to "h, i, ,  t, h, e, r, e, !"
set b to "h, o, w,  , a, r, e,  , y, o, u, ?"
set c to "w, h, e, r, e,  , d, o,  , y, o, u,  , w, a, n, t,  , t, o,  , b, e, g, i, n, ?"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set the list_items to every text item of the a
set d to list_items
set e to count of list_items
set f to 0
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set the m to every text item of the b
set g to m
set h to count of m
set i to 0
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ", "
set the n to every text item of the c
set j to n
set k to count of n
set l to 0
tell application "System Events"
repeat e times
    set f to f + 1
    delay (random number from 0.05 to 0.3)
    keystroke item f of d
end repeat
key code 36
repeat h times
    set i to i + 1
    delay (random number from 0.05 to 0.3)
    keystroke item i of g
end repeat
key code 36
repeat k times
    set l to l + 1
    delay (random number from 0.05 to 0.3)
    keystroke item l of j
end repeat
end tell
```